# How to use <s:iterator> or other struts tags to iterate part of a list

Tags: struts2, struts, struts-html

I have a list named `projectList`. I have dealt with the first 3 elements in the list in a different way, then I want to iterate the `projectList` from index=3 to the end.

How should I achieve this?
Either the solution with pure struts tags or a solution mixed with Javascript would be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```
<s:iterator value="projectList" status="itstatus">
         <s:if test="#itstatus.index > 3">
        <!-- YOUR CODE -->
         </s:if>
         <s:else>
            <!-- YOUR CODE -->
         </s:else>
</s:iterator>
```

I can't test it right now, so maybe it has some errors. Good Luck!